# R Histogramm with if condition

Tags: r, histogram

I have a dataset showing coal fired power plants and their 'Remaining_lifetime' and want to present the information on their lifetime in a histogram. This is easy:

```
hist(data_all$Remaining_lifetime)
```

Now, I want a second plot that shows the remaining lifetime if another variable 'Signatory' == 1. I thought I could do this using the function 'if', but it does not work.

I also tried a ggplot:

```
gplot(subset(data_all,wsignatory_dummy =="1")
         + geom_bar(aes(data_all$Remaining_lifetime))
          )
```

Which does not work either. Googling did not help and I could not find an answer here - so hoping for help!

Comment: Try subsetting the data using [indexing]:  `hist(data_all$Remaining_lifetime[data_all$Signatory == 1])`

Comment: In the ggplot code, remove `data_all$` from `aes()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this using dplyr.

```
data_all %>% filter(Signatory == 1) %>% ggplot(.) + geom_bar(aes(Remaining_lifetime))
```

This filters the dataset first, only keeping the rows where Signatory == 1. This is used as input for `geom_bar` which is what you want I think. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine. In fact, all three stated options work equally good and produce the same result. Thanks for the help!